# Would it be wrong to tell askers of legitimate C++/CLI questions to go develop relevant background skills first?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

Half or more of the C++/CLI questions posted every day demonstrate, through fundamental misunderstanding of OOP, that the asker has never learned either standard C++ or C#, or even a similar managed language such as Java, VB.NET, or F#.

I feel that C++/CLI is not a language for beginners, it's for users who have run up against limits of p/invoke (or C# generally) and want to use features like C++ templates, deterministics destruction, C++ interop, and large existing C++ code bases.

Would the SO community favor or frown on telling these users that they aren't ready to try C++/CLI until they learn either C# (or standard C++, depending on the question) first?

Examples:

- [Windows Form Question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575028/windows-form-question)
- [How to pass variables from Class to Object in C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575443/how-to-pass-variables-from-class-to-object-in-c-cli)
- [How to use "this" in a thread!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549611/how-to-use-this-in-a-thread)
- [Can a thread be accessed from two forms in a Windows forms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547064/can-a-thread-be-accessed-from-two-forms-in-a-windows-forms-application)

Comment: I doubt this is limited to C++/CLI

Comment: Would the "bad-question" tag apply to this question?

Comment: @Andrew: Probably.  I'll add it.  I'm not as familiar with commonly used tags on meta as the main SO site.

Comment: I dunno about wrong or not, but it's certainly a challenge to word such a response in a way that remains "nice."

Comment: @Charles: I tend to favor "most helpful" over "nice".  Usually the two don't conflict, sometimes they do, but I can think of many worse things to be known as than "blunt".

Comment: Considering that the second post contains "CIS170CLab6B", I'm guessing that at least one of the posters doesn't have a choice of which language to use. Even better, that post has a comment suggesting that the OP attend a C++ class!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, that's not okay.  C++/CLI is a newbie language, first one everybody tries after they download the C++ Express edition.  There is no other way to get something decent looking going in that edition in a week or less.  Newbie programmers ask newbie questions, they are just not helped with a crusty guru that's worn out from the questions.

Which is all rather counter to what you think C++/CLI should be used for.  Probably the best way to resolve that is talk to Microsoft.  You are a C++ MVP, feedback is expected and appreciated.  Allen Li or Diego Dagum are probably your best bet to get that started.

Comment: You're right, I do have some points to make to Allen and Diego when I think about it.  Most students taking a C++ class shouldn't be ending up with Visual C++ Express (MS provides VS for free to students), shouldn't be using C++/CLI (their code will fail when the TA tries to compile with gcc on linux), and probably aren't being asked for a GUI, they got one by accident due to new project wizard default settings.  That covers just about everyone who doesn't have a choice about what language to use.  And MS could easily help this problem with a few well-placed links.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing that, you could point them to a FAQ page explaining basic things you think they are lacking. There are all kind of FAQs on the net and easy to find.